# How to move images of docker in aufs directory to overlay2?

Tags: linux, docker

I update my kernel of Debian from 3.x to 4.x.
Docker storage become overlay2.

```
ls /var/lib/docker/ 
containers  image  network  overlay2  plugins  swarm  tmp  trust  volumes
```

old directory structure is

```
aufs  containers  graph  image  init  linkgraph.db  network  plugins  repositories-aufs  swarm  tmp  tmp-old  trust  volumes
```

My docker images and contains storage in aufs directory, I can not start docker service with old directory. how can I move my images from old directory to new one?

Comment: This is a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745304

Comment: You manually updated the kernel, or it was a debian upgrade?